# Surrender control from Pipeline to an HttpHandler

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, sitecore, httphandler

I have a problem with a website. The server is IIS 7, running ASP.NET on the .NET 4.0 CLR. We are hosting a Sitecore application and I hesitated in adding it as a tag, because I really feel it's more the 'why' of the question and not necessarily related to the underlying tech that's causing the problem.

One of the things Sitecore does is add a boatload of custom pipelines. One of these pipelines is called the `LayoutResolverPipeline`, which is responsible for determining the path to the layout file the requested page will use. We've come up with a terribly useful and complicated way of hosting global content items across multiple domains. Which domain will serve which items is completely configurable through the Administrator web GUI (aka the Sitecore shell). The end goal is to make it possible for our marketing/consumer experience team to run multivariate testing to find the best user experience.

To that end, we have a 'launch' page that is responsible for considering everything about the current user, everything about the current system and domain settings, and determines which experience to give the customer. For most domains, this comes down to a weighted roll of the dice - for the test results to be statistically sound, they have to be sufficiently random. It is written as an `IHttpHandler` and it stores its decisions in the `HttpContext.Current.Session` (which is accomplished by also having it implement the `IRequiresSessionState` interface). The decision is stored so that if the customer decides to backtrack, we don't roll the dice again and instead give them a consistent experience for the duration of their visit. The decision is carried out by the handler issuing a 302 redirect for the next page in the customer's visit.

The launch handler is defined in the web.config file in the usual way:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
    <add verb="*" path="launch.ashx"
       type="CMS.HttpHandlers.LaunchRequestHandler, CMS"
       name="LaunchHandler"/>
```

We occasionally do business with partners who, for whatever reason, don't want the resultant 302 between their page and ours. They will instead link directly to a certain customer experience. Over time, however, we depreciate, move or obsolete whole user experiences, which for certain demanding and lazy partners result in lingering links to unsupported or non-existent items. We also have to handle the case of people mis-typing, mis-remembering, mis-linking, revisiting from their browser history or just trying random urls.

These latter cases have resulted in some nasty exceptions in the `LayoutResolverPipeline`. I am trying to resolve these exceptions by having it fall back to the `LaunchHandler` if it can't figure out what to do. I have this implemented as a Redirect, but I would like to simply invoke the `LaunchHandler` directly; it is going to do a 301 to a different item, anyways, and having multiple redirects on a single request is a costly waste of resources that I would like to avoid.

Enough background. The problem is that `LayoutResolverPipeline` is bound to the `HttpBeginRequest` portion of the IIS processing stack, which is well before the Session information is ready. This is a constraint of Sitecore's and it can't be moved without solving a whole load of other problems.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to pass control to a specific `IHttpHandler` other than redirecting to the URL it is bound to?
2. Is there a way to rejoin the code a later point in the event pipeline? I suppose this would mean binding to the `Application.PostAcquireRequestState` event for a single request only, which sounds ludicrous.
3. Is there a way to acquire session state information early?

I'm of course open to suggestions for how I might be doing it completely wrong. Oh, and if you know of a more useful tag to throw on it for the Asp.net/IIS pipeline specifically, I wasn't able to find one that wasn't a read herring. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to go manually invoking any handlers... that sounds pretty hacky.  What about using **Server.Transfer()** here instead of a 301 Redirect?  Then it's transparent on the user's end.  Of course the disadvantage there is that it doesn't update the apparent URL, but you can't do that without *some* sort of redirect going on.

Comment: +1 for `Server.Transfer()`, that's good stuff. Apparently it is fraught with peril for use in Sitecore precisely because they have so many pipelines that need to set up all their internal state stuff. I did find [this](http://www.victorfeinman.com/2011/05/server-side-redirect-to-a-sitecore-item/) but what I'm doing is sufficently different that it doesn't work off the shelf. I'll come back and accept your answer if I can get it working for me, but leaving it open for now to solicit other suggestions.